# Loopback crash in callback when calling on resetPasswordRequest more then one

Tags: node.js, callback, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to make my own remote method to reset a password. The user just has to put the email in the path and the server will send the accessToken as response.

```
MyUser.remoteMethod('requestPasswordReset',
        {
          http: {path: '/reset/:usermail', verb: 'post'},
          accepts: [{arg: 'usermail', type: 'string', required: true, http: {source: 'path'}}],
          returns: {root: true, type: 'object'},
          description: 'Allows Users to request a password reset, returns an error if the specified email does not exist'
        }
);

MyUser.requestPasswordReset = function (usermail, next) {
    MyUser.resetPassword({email: usermail}, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err);
      }
      else {
        MyUser.on('resetPasswordRequest', function (info) {

          console.log('next will be executed, but crashes the second time');
          next(null, info.accessToken.id); 
        });
      }
    })
  };
```

The first time I make a request to `/reset/:usermail` everthing works perfect, but the second time I run the request the application crashes with follow error

> Can't set headers after they are sent

I know this error typically occurs when calling more callbacks. 
If I give an other error argument to the callback for. ex.`next('abc')` in stead of null `next(null, info.accessToken.id);` the application doesn't crashes

Answer (score 0):

I have found the cause of the error. `MyUser.on('resetPasswordRequest', function (info))` is making a listener. So every time `requestPasswordReset` is called, a new listener is created. When the user makes the request for the second time, there are two listeners and they both send a response. Putting `MyUser.on('resetPasswordRequest', function (info))` in the root of the js file lost the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by saying "putting. in the root of the js?"

Comment: @TimTuckle I mean moving the function to the root of the file